# ¿Como llamo el valor de un método de otra clase dentro de un parámetro de un if?

Tags: java

Actualizacion:
Mi problema es este!
Tengo dos clases, y en una clase tengo un if. Que por lo tanto quiero saber el retorno de la otra clase de su metodo. Porque si es el del metodo donde puse solamente el if es asi.

```java
If ( Metodo() == true){}
```

Es decir por ej mi primera clase es asi.

```java
public class Persona {
    private int salidas=11;
    
    public Persona(int salidas) {
        this.salidas = salidas;
    }
    

    boolean muchassalidas () {
        boolean respuesta = false;
        if (salidas > 10) {
            respuesta = true;
        }
        else {
            respuesta = false;
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
    
    public boolean comprobacion() {
        boolean respuesta = false;
        if  (muchassalidas() == true && ????? **mayorACinco() == true**) {
        respuesta = true;
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

```java
public class Cont {

    Int contador=6;
    
    public Cont(Int contador) {
        this.contador = contador;
        
    }

    public boolean mayorACinco() {
        boolean respuesta = true;
        if(contador>5) {
            respuesta=true;
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
    
}
```

Lo que quiero es que el metodo donde esta en la CLASE CONT.
Llevarlo a la clase PERSONA y hacer la comprobacion de su retorno como hice con muchassalidas.

Comment: Estas describiendo metodos x y z pero los utilizas como si fueran atributos (`A.x` y `B.z`). Puedes aclarar si son metodos, de otra manera deberias referenciarlos como `A.x()` y `B.z()`

Comment: Si, lo siento. Ahi lo arregle!

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema realmente, ¿llamar a los métodos o utilizar lo que devuelven para el `if`? ¿Quieres hacer `if (A.x() == true && B.z() == true)`? Eso tiene que funcionar. Tanto A como B deben ser instancias de la clase, y no la clase en sí, a no ser que estos métodos sean estáticos.

Answer (score 2):

Cualquier método en Java se ejecuta sobre un objeto, por ello se puede decir que un objeto ejecuta un método. Y ten en cuenta que en Java todo son objetos, salvo variables de tipos primitivos como `int` o `char` (existen las clases envolventes para convertir estas variables en objetos). Incluso las clases en Java son objetos que puedes manipular como otro cualquiera (tienen atributos y métodos que puedes ejecutar).

Cuando defines una clase cualquiera.

```
public class A {
    // ... Atributos y constructores

    public boolean metodoInstancia() {
        // ... Código que devuelve un booleano
    }

    public static boolean meotodoClase() {
        // ... Código que devuelve un booleano
    }
}
```

Los métodos definidos se ejecutan a través de objetos.

En el caso del método `metodoInstancia` se necesita un objeto de la clase `A` para que ejecute dicho método. A cualquier objeto de una clase cualquiera además se le llama instancia de la clase.

```
A instancia = new A();
instancia.metodoInstancia();
```

Un método cualquiera que no contenga la palabra `static` es un método de instancia, y necesitas un objeto o instancia de la clase en la que está definido para poder ejecutarlo.

Ahora bien, cuando un método lleva la palabra clave `static`, el método se dice que es un método de clase, y se ejecuta a través de la propia clase, ya que es un objeto que puede ejecutar métodos (en concreto los estáticos).

```
A.metodoClase();
```

No hace falta crear ninguna instancia de la clase `A` para ejecutar sus métodos de clase.

También, ten en cuenta que desde una clase A, puedes llamar a métodos de clase A omitiendo el nombre de la clase, porque se sobre entiende, pero desde fuera de la clase siempre tendrás que escribirlo.

Y de igual forma, desde un método de instancia puedes llamar a otro método de instancia sin crear otro objeto de la clase para ejecutar dicho método, porque el objeto inicial que empezó la primera llamada (`this`) será el que ejecute la segunda llamada.

Además, desde un método de instancia puedes llamar a un método de clase, ya que siempre tienes disponible la referencia al objeto que representa a la clase; pero desde un método de clase no puedes llamar a un método de instancia directamente a través de `this`, pero sí a través de un objeto de la clase A creado explícitamente, o recibido como parámetro.

```
public class A {
    public static bool metodoClase() { /* ... */ }

    public bool metodoInstancia() { /* ... */ }

    public static bool metodoClase2() {
        metodoClase();    // Llamada con clase A implícita
        A.metodoClase();  // Llamada con clase A explícita

        A a = new A();
        a.metodoInstancia();  // Llamada a método de instancia con un objeto de la clase A (this no existe en los métodos estáticos)
    }

    public bool metodoInstancia2() {
        metodoInstancia();    // Llamada con objeto this implícito
        this.metodoInstancia();    // Llamada con objeto this explícito
        A a = new A();
        a.metodoInstancia();       // Esta vez "a" ejecutará el método de instancia (a != this)

        metodoClase();    // Llamada a método de clase desde método de instancia
        A.metodoClase();  // Esta vez con clase A explícita

        // ...
    }
}
```

Entonces, respondiendo a tu pregunta. Dependiendo de cómo hayas definido esos métodos, podrás tener acceso a ellos a través de una instancia de la clase, o a través de la propia clase.

Si suponemos que el método que hace uso de los otros 2 está en A, necesitarás un objeto de la clase B (no nulo).

```
public class A {
    // ...
    public boolean metodoCompuesto() {
        B instanciaB = new B();
        return this.x() && instanciaB.z();
    }

    public boolean metodoCompuesto(B b) {
        return x() && b.z();
    }
}
```

Pero si los métodos `x` y `z` son métodos de clase (estáticos):

```
public class A {
    // ...
    public static boolean metodoDeClaseCompuesto() {
        return x() && B.z();    // A.x() con A implícita
    }

    public boolean metodoInstanciaCompuesto() {
        return x() && B.z();    // A.x() con A implícita
    }
}
```

Nótese que la segunda versión, que es un método de instancia, no hace uso de la instancia que ha hecho la llamada al método compuesto, lo que no tiene sentido. En este ejemplo la versión estática de método compuesto es la más apropiada.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo!